# Multiple backpresses skips the activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In Android, for example, when I create an app that uses a login screen, skips the login activity when its continuously back pressed. Can I know why this happens and how do I make sure that the user completes the activity first and then move to next activity?

Comment: your manifest should declare what is the launching activity, and you need to set an explicit intent to navigate to the next activity. all activity transactions are intent based

Comment: by default we have stack of activities, you must be aware of that, it might look like skipping activity on sequential back presses, do you want to hold user on login screen ?